# Why is this function saying "Only simple variable patterns can be bound in 'let rec' constructs"?

Tags: f#

I am just getting started with F# and am trying Problem Euler problem #3. To find primes I came up with the following code to compute all primes up to a maximum number:

```
let rec allPrimes foundPrimes, current, max =
    // make sure the current number isn't too high
    //   or the current number isn't divisible by any known primes
    if current >= max then
        foundPrimes
    else
        let nextValue = current + 1

        if not List.exists (fun x -> current % x = 0L) foundPrimes then
            allPrimes foundPrimes nextValue max
        else
            allPrimes (foundPrimes :: current) nextValue max
```

Unfortunately, this gives the error:

> Only simple variable patterns can be bound in 'let rec' constructs

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to put the commas in the declaration - change

```
let rec allPrimes foundPrimes, current, max =
```

to

```
let rec allPrimes foundPrimes current max =
```

The correct version of your original would be

```
let rec allPrimes (foundPrimes, current, max) =
```

note the brackets around the tuple.  However, this would require modifying the recursive calls to also use tuple form.  In the original version the compiler thinks you are trying to do something like

```
let a,b,c=1,2,3
```

which won't work for recursive functions.